# --font-size not working as a parameter inside mgt-person-card

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I have been using the css variables in the mgt-person component to great success

```
mgt-person {
    --font-size: 14px;
    --font-weight: 400;
}
```

But in the mgt-person-card the font-size property doesn't seem to affect anything? The documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/person-card seems to suggest that this should work? Or am I missing something?

```
mgt-person-card {
  --font-size: 1px;
  --font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, it looks like the documentation isn't correctly matching the current variables. I posted an issue on the repository, with more information here:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/333

and I will follow up with the subsequent PR soon.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the code with the correct variables? I can't see it, and we are trying to integrate this right now.

Comment: The variable wasn't exposed correctly, since the `mgt-person-card` is dependent on the`mgt-person` component. 

A PR correcting this and adding more customization to the component has been pushed here:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/pull/363

This will be reflected in the 1.2.0 version of the toolkit.